# I don't want my private method even to be displayed outside my class even by using reflection?

Tags: java

One can call and see `private` methods using reflection by calling `getDeclaredMethod`.
What can I do if I don't want my `private` method even to be displayed outside my class?

Comment: You can't. Why do you want to hide private method using reflection? what is your use case?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1492847/1073063](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1492847/1073063)

Answer (score 3):

You're out of luck, unfortunately. You could obfuscate the name (simply name it to something non-obvious) but other than that you can't really do anything.

Note also someone can decompile your class. So any functionality is visible, and in this case obfuscation will hide the intent, but not the code.

Answer (score 3):

The only option is to inline it so it doesn't appear.  Methods are always visible via reflection.